'of' in 'What has become of him? and "It is kind of you to say so."

What has become of him?


It is kind of you to say so.

The usage of 'of' in terms of grammar is the same between the two sentences?
Why can't we use 'for' like "What has become for him?"

A similar question and answer can be found here

The answer to "Why?" is really only "because that's how English is".  The choice of prepositions often looks arbitrary, but there is usually one way that is "native" and everything else is not.

The phrase is become of, not become for.
Become of someone/something is a
phrasal verb
as defined in Cambridge Dictionary:

If you ask what became of someone or something, you want to know where they are and what happened to them.


The same structure as "What will happen to you?": What will become of you?; 'happen' needs 'to' and 'become' needs 'of'?

@gomadeng I guess so. I was going to say that "happen to" isn't really a phrase the way "become of" is, but it has its own dictionary entry as a phrase.

@gomadeng, we use become of and happen to as they are the established phrases.  Thanks, Andy Bonner. Yes, happen to is found also in Cambridge Dictionary: happen to someone/something

Yes, "become of" is an established phrase. I cannot immediately think of another modern expression that uses "of" in a similar way. It sounds old-fashioned to me.

Preposition of can have the function of attributing something to its object, such that these originals could be rephrased with the copula (or other linking verb) and a predicative complement:

It is kind of you to say so => You are kind to say so.

and

What has become of him? => He is what now? He has become what?  (i.e. I want some information about him; I am ignorant about his current circumstances.)

P.S. Prepositional phrases can contribute meaning to a verb even when the verb with that particular preposition does not have phrasal-verb status:

It happened to us too.
The day was so wonderful and went by so quickly that when its light faded to dusk we  wondered what had become of the time.

The natural parsing rhythms of those sentences do not make the prepositions to and of a quasi-enclitic attachment to the verb, as in we find with the phrasal verb "take off".
The rhythm is:

Take off ... your coat.

not:

Take ... off your coat.

But

It happened ... to us too.

not:

It happened to ... us too.

With "what had become of the time" it is maybe a little murkier.  I would say it so:

... what had become ... of the time

not:

... what had become of ...  the time.

Perhaps some speakers would choose the latter when saying that phrase (emphasis on saying, not pondering, those words).
In this questioning sense (what happened to it? where did it go?) become of something is not used on an everyday basis as "take off" is ("take off your shoes") but is rather more "elevated" speech.  We all know from our everyday use what the preposition "off" means in "take off your shoes". There is a simple physicality to that preposition, whereas of is abstract: its function is not spatial and physical but conceptual, attributing something (a state, a condition, a trait) to its grammtical object.

"kind of you" and similar: An academic article about this pattern: Goldberg and Herbst, 2021.

The article isn't really relevant to how the preposition works; but in saying that this construction "evaluates the agent" (which, in the OP's example, is the one who "says so") the article and my answer are in agreement; the function of "of" in this pattern is to attribute something (a character trait of some kind) to the object of the preposition (the "agent", the one who does the action of the verb in the infinitival clause complement)

To complement the other answers, I would like to offer a different perspective. The word 'of' suggests that something originates in something else - so one could interpret 'What has become of him?' as 'What has he become that originated in him?' - 'become of' describes something somehow has evolved naturally, in a sense.
The word 'for', in contrast, suggests something like 'instead of' or 'on behalf of'. I don't think 'What has become for him?' makes sense.
